# Create Folders By File Name With Delimiter

Tags: file, directory, move

I'm trying to modify a script the Magoo posted to create folders based on file names and move associated files to those directories.  There are 2-4 files for each instance with the same name but with different extensions. The names are delimited with - (hyphen). These are music files and therefore there will be multiple sets that should get moved into folders that are titles to reflect everything before the delimiter.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=F:\Test"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR /f "delims=-" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d *.mp3 *.cdg *.PLX '
  ) DO (
 SET "filename=%%a"
 SET "dirname=%%a"
 CALL :genmove
)
popd

GOTO :EOF

:genmove
IF "%dirname:~-1%" neq " " set "dirname=%dirname:~0,-1%"&goto genmove
set "dirname=%dirname:~0,-1%"
    MD "%dirname%"
    MOVE "%filename%" ".\%dirname%\"
GOTO :eof
```

My issues so far:

- If I define the delimiter the folders are created properly but the
  files aren't moved.
- If I eliminate the delimiter the files are moved
  but each set is moved into a unique folder with the entire file
  name.
- Using `*.*` in the "dir" string didn't work, so I defined each extension

Ant help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I just added an `*` to `MOVE "%filename%" ".\%dirname%\"`

Making it `MOVE "%filename%*" ".\%dirname%\"`

That moves the collective files to the appropriate directories.  I would still like to have a wildcard in the `FOR /f` instead of defining each type of extension, but this works for now.